# Bank details in Tax returns ITR1 - AY 2017-18

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, savings, bank-account

In ITR1, Under Tax paid and Verification, it says to give all Bank Account details.

I am from India, and have 3 bank accounts,
1) Bank of India, 2) Karnataka Bank Ltd, 3) Punjab National Bank.

- I am 1st Account holder in Bank of India.
- 2nd account holder in Karnataka Bank Ltd (First holder is my Mother)
- 2nd account holder in Punjab National Bank (First holder is my Father).

Questions:

1. Can I fill only 1 bank account since I am first holder?
2. Is it necessary to fill all 3 Bank account details in ITR1 since I am 2ND Holder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I fill only 1 bank account since I am first holder?

To be safe, it is recommended that you declare all the account numbers.

> Is it necessary to fill all 3 Bank account details in ITR1 since I am 2ND Holder?

It is advisable to declare all the account numbers. The guideline is not clear if joint account holders where you are second holder need to be declared or not.